# how to show two tables one in horizontal and one in vertical order asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am new to ASP.NET. I am making a user interface which is using MSSQL Server database. I have two tables Table1 and Table2. Table1 has column category and Table2 has column Description.

I need to show these two tables as follows.

Table1.Category in horizontal and Table2.Description in vertical order and show them just like Excel rows and columns.

What I did so far is I used **ListView** for Table1 and select the direction to horizontal from property builder.For table2 I used another Listview. Please let me know if I am going in right direction or I should to do in some other way. Thanks !

Comment: If you are indeed using the .NET MVC framework, you are definitely going to wrong way.  Those server side controls are web forms only.  Even if you can hammer them into your Views, MVC is simply not built to support the things that ListView, DataGridView, etc rely on, such as ViewState.

Comment: Then what do you think which approach will be good to follow? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is a pretty broad request that you are making that would encompass creating a ViewModel, a controller/action to populate that ViewModel, creating the View and handling the HTML mark up to output your tables.  I would suggest taking a look at the MVC tutorials on Razor, Views and View Models.  As you work through those, if you have a specific question on an implementation or how to, come back and ask about that.  http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/displaying-data